# Error on opening a world even it exists gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo-simu

`dad@ubuntu:~$ gazebo --verbose  world/iris_arducopter_runway.world`

When I run this code the output is as follows. The error is about the loading of the world file but it exists. In advance, the world is opened as empty world.

```
Error opening log file: "/home/dad/.gazebo/client-11345/gzclient.log"
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 9.19.0
Copyright (C) 2012 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Error opening log file: "/home/dad/.gazebo/client-11345/default.log"
[Msg] Waiting for master.
Error opening log file: "/home/dad/.gazebo/server-11345/gzserver.log"
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 9.19.0
Copyright (C) 2012 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Error opening log file: "/home/dad/.gazebo/server-11345/default.log"
[Msg] Waiting for master.
[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
[Msg] Publicized address: 192.168.139.137
[Wrn] [FuelModelDatabase.cc:248] URI not supported by Fuel [world/iris_arducopter_runway.world]
[Wrn] [SystemPaths.cc:464] File or path does not exist [""] [world/iris_arducopter_runway.world]
[Err] [Server.cc:411] Could not open file[world/iris_arducopter_runway.world]
[Wrn] [Server.cc:362] Falling back on worlds/empty.world
[Msg] Loading world file [/usr/share/gazebo-9/worlds/empty.world]
[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
[Msg] Publicized address: 192.168.139.137
```

I got this bold error when I am trying to launch any default worlds.

`[Err] [Server.cc:411] Could not open file[world/iris_arducopter_runway.world]`

UPDATE:

Now this problem is not general one. I tried it for cessna_demo.world and after some stuck on load states the simulation world loaded completely.

Comment: just give absolute path

Comment: I also tried in the absolute directory, similarly. But it didn't solve.